# Codeigniter - send variable within link

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is this a good/bad practice to send variable along with the link or there is a better way in CI?

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
       echo "<li><a href='samples?tempid=" .$row->id. "'>" .$row->name. "</a></li>";

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: All is good when the end is rendered in HTML. :P

Answer (score -1):

try to change with this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{

    echo "<li>".anchor('samples/tempid/'.$row->id,$row->name)."</li>";

}
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.